# What does two percent % symbols mean in this Makefile sentence?

Tags: makefile

I encountered this line of code in Makefile. I have tried so hard to find an explanation but not able to. Can someone pass a hint if you have a clue? In particular, what does symbol %= mean in this Makefile sentence.

```
ifndef VARA
    VARB := $(CURDIR:/Dev/home/ajhome/%=/home/%)
    export VARA:= $(VARB)
endif
```

Appreciate a lot in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That shouldn't be read as a `%=`, the `%` and `=` have different functions. It's a pattern substitution:

```
$(VARNAME:pattern1=pattern2)
```

And `%` is a placeholder in the pattern. This is often used (for example) to get the name of object files from source files, for example

```
SRCS = foo.c bar.c
OBJS = $(SRCS:%.c=%.o)

# $(OBJS) is foo.o bar.o
```

In your case, it will take the directory in `$(CURDIR)` and replace the `/Dev/home/ajhome/` at its beginning with `/home/`. Well, if `$(CURDIR)` is a list of directories, it will do so for each one of them, but the variable name suggests that there's only one in them, so I'm going with that.

Comment: How wonderful and crystal clear! As pointed out, it should not read %=, I will update the title to make it not misleading. Now you see how it confused me, as I am off the track from the beginning. Thank you so much again.

Comment: The (in my experience) slightly more common `$(SRCS:.c=.o)` is also the same thing but with an implicit pattern/`%` at the start.